# How to randomly place a certain block over the map within a radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Let say I choose diamond block, I wanna place the block randomly all over the surface within a radius of 100 blocks. Is there a mod or command to do this kind of work?

Comment: there might be a mod but if you want a command it would take 1 block per diamond block you wanna place.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank I have no idea about commands and stuff. That's why I'm asking for a mod or commands out there that do so.

Comment: And expecting us to help you when you've done nothing yourself won't get a good reception here.  You show effort, and users respond to that. You don't, and people are less likely to even want to help.

Answer (score 0):

1. you'd go with `/spreadplayers` in the way that you randomly spread an entity over the area and just set a diamond block wherever it lands.
   With this method you need to be aware of the fact that it can get spread to the same location again, resulting in a tower of blocks. if you want to prevent that either go with the second way or implement something to combat that.
2. or you use 100 entities and do everything at the same time. it's quicker but more resource intensive.